# Get link which matches exact word

Tags: html, python-3.x, string

Hi I have many links from which I only need links which match exact words like join, career etc.

For example

```
links = ['https://enzymocore.com/news/august-2015-joint-venture-in-peru/'  ,  'https://enzymocore.com/join-us'].
```

So if my keyword is join then I should only get the second link not the first one.
Here is my current code:

```
for link in links:
   if 'join' in link:
      finallink.append(link)
```

but from this code I am getting both because in first link the word 'joint' contain 'join'.

Comment: Why don't you use a regex then?

Comment: How do you separate words in the URLs? If `-` is the separator then you can check `if 'join-' in link:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this regex check? If any letter (a to z or A to Z) at `start` of at `end` of the target like `join` or `career` then the link is not a match.

```py
import re

final_links = []

links = [
    'https://enzymocore.com/news/august-2015-joint-venture-in-peru/',
    'https://enzymocore.com/join-us'
]

for link in links:
    if re.search(r"[^a-zA-Z](join|career)[^a-zA-Z]", link):
        print(link)
        final_list.append(link)
```